# Getting the deleted record?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate. i am deleting record using delete method as below.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.delete(pojotobedeleted);
```

my requirement is after deleting the record, it should return the same deleted record. How can i get the deleted record?

Thanks!

Comment: `return pojotobedeleted;`?

Comment: Add a listener to handle lifecycle event.

Comment: returning pojotobedeleted kinda works, but surely if you need the pojo don't delete it until you have finished with it. The transient pojo will contain an id, which is no longer on datastore so if the pojo is altered in anyway the changes can;t be persisted - so wants the point

Answer (score 0):

I'd say

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
pojotobedeleted = session.load(Pojo.class, id);  /* not necessary if loaded before */
session.delete(pojotobedeleted);
return pojotobedeleted;
```

Sure there is an extra select statement for doing so, but that is the same with native SQL. The SQL delete does not return the deleted rows, and hibernate can't be better that native SQL.

(If this is not what you wants then I don't understand your question: What is the goal, why not like in my example?)